# Setting value of a nested, non-repeating Protocol Buffers message in Python

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

All,
Apologies in advance for the novice question, but I cannot figure out how to set the value of a nested, *non repeating* message. For repeating message types I can define a variable as the nested message with .add() and then being setting parameters in a straight-forward fashion. For non-repeating message types though, I cannot make this work.

I have the following schema:

```
syntax="proto2";
package pkgName;

message OuterLayer
{
    required string thing = 1;
    message InnerLayer 
    {
        optional string otherthing = 1;

    }
```

I would have thought I could do something like this:

```
message = proto_pb2.OuterLayer()
message.InnerLayer.otherthing = "bar"
```

Now - this doesn't fail, but when I print the message after setting this, I do not see the contents, leading me to believe that it isn't working.  For example if I set a parameter at the top level:

```
message.thing = "foo"
```

and then print this:

```
print(message)
```

I see:

```
"thing" : "foo"
```

… but not the next layer down's contents.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well I feel rather foolish, but it was non-obvious to me. Hopefully this helps someone else. As best I can tell, the correct way to do this is to modify my schema with an additional field:

```
syntax="proto2";
package pkgName;

message OuterLayer
{
    required string thing = 1;
    message InnerLayer 
    {
        optional string otherthing = 1;

    }
    optional InnerLayer innerlevel = 2;
```

Now that that is done, you can do as you would expect:

```
message.innerlevel.otherthing = "foo"
```